# How do I make the Google Assistant notify me when I get email from a specific person using my S8?

Tags: gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-8, google-assistant

I have a Google Mini & the IFTTT app but I can't figure out how to make Google mini make a voice notification when email from a specific user arrives. Is there a way to do this?

I use Gmail & have an S8.